# Why doesn't Angular notice that this variable's value has changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having problems with a very simple Angular app. [Here's a CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogZPZq); the same code is below.

In this app, you click on a button to eat bananas, and the total number of bananas that you've eaten is shown on the page. After each click, there should be a one-second cooldown before you can eat another banana.

To accomplish this, I've done the following:

- `$scope.cooling_down` is a boolean.
- `$scope.can_eat_banana` is a function which returns `true` or `false`, indicating whether or not the "Eat a Banana" button should be usable. Basically, it returns true if `$scope.cooling_down` is false.
- The "Eat a Banana" button has `ng-disabled="!can_eat_banana()"`.
- When the user clicks on the "Eat a Banana" button, I set `$scope.cooling_down` to `true`, and use `window.setTimeout()` to schedule a callback to set it back to `false` one second later.

(You may ask: why not get rid of `$scope.can_eat_banana()` altogether, and simply use `ng-disabled="cooling_down"` on the button? Answer: because, as the game develops, the logic determining whether or not the player can eat a banana will become more complex. And it seems really messy to put that logic in the view.)

So, when I run this test case, this is what happens:

1. I load the page. Initially, the button is enabled.
2. I click on the "Eat a Banana" button. As expected, my code sets `$scope.cooling_down` to `true`, and the button becomes disabled. So far, so good.
3. One second later, the callback that I passed into `window.setTimeout()` fires. (I have a `console.log()` as the first line in the callback to confirm that it's running.) This callback sets `$scope.cooling_down` back to `false`. (You can look at the console to confirm that the value was updated.) ***But:*** Angular doesn't notice that the value has changed. The button doesn't become re-enabled, and the `{{cooling_down}}` token on the page stays stuck on `true`.

Why? Why does Angular notice the *first* time the value changes (when it gets changed to `true` after the user clicks on the button), but not notice the *second* time (when the callback fires and sets it back to `false`)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="game">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Incredibly Stupid Banana Game</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="GameController">

    <p>You have eaten {{bananas_eaten}} bananas.</p>

    <button type="button" ng-click="eat_banana()" ng-disabled="!can_eat_banana()">Eat a Banana</button>

    <p>[current value of cooling_down: {{cooling_down}}]</p>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        ( function() {

            var app = angular.module( "game", [] );

            app.controller( "GameController", [ "$scope", function( $scope ) {

                $scope.bananas_eaten = 0;
                $scope.cooling_down = false;

                $scope.eat_banana = function() {
                    $scope.bananas_eaten++;
                    $scope.cooling_down = true;
                    window.setTimeout( function() {
                        console.log( "setTimeout callback fired" );
                        $scope.cooling_down = false;
                        console.log( "Current value of cooling_down: " + $scope.cooling_down );
                    }, 1000 );
                };

                $scope.can_eat_banana = function() {
                    return !$scope.cooling_down;
                };

            } ] );

        }() );

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use the built-in $timeout, which will cause a digest to occur upon completion of the callback, thus updating the ui.

Comment: I would suggest not using the `can_eat_banana` function and instead using a simple boolean value. I know, it'l get more complex, but the more complex the function gets the less responsive your app will be because each digest will result in that function getting called multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

Angular does not run its digest loop again after a `window.setTimeout()` (indeed, it is not even notified about it).

Use `$timeout()` instead.

Comment: If you're wondering why: `setTimeout` is an asynchronous function. Angular can only handle synchronous functions. Any time you want to use an asynchronous function, make sure to use the angular equivalent (it'll have a `$` before the function name)

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

For the benefit of readers: you'll have to use dependency injection to inject $timeout into your controller function before you can use it.

Comment: I now understand that the first update works because Angular automatically runs a digest cycle after handling the `ng-click`. But I thought that Angular worked by polling variables regularly (like, several times per second), and updating the view whenever it finds a "dirty" value. So I don't understand why it doesn't pick up on the second change. Am I misunderstanding the way that Angular works?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that I'm misunderstanding. I read a blog post which suggested that Angular just constantly, blindly looks for updates to values, but either the post was poorly explained or I misinterpreted it. Angular only checks for dirty values (i.e., runs a digest cycle) when scope.$apply() is called, which can happen automatically (after something which might be expected to cause a change happens) or when called manually by client code. I was *wondering* how constant scanning could possibly be performant...

Answer (score 1):

When you update the model (the property of the scope,) a digest has to occur for that change to affect the UI. By the time the window.setTimeout has completed, the original digest (which was caused by a click) has long since finished and another isn't started, so the UI is never updated.

To solve this, replace `window.setTimeout` with the `$timeout` service which will start another digest upon the completion of the timeout.